# R Extract name of dataframe and mutate new column

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataframe of t.tests with 2 columns: objects and their p.value:

```
`t.test>1sd` <- tibble( 
object = c('obj1','obj2','obj3'),
p.value= c(0.45,0.34,0.02)
)

> `t.test>1sd`
# A tibble: 3 x 2
object p.value
<chr>    <dbl>
1 obj1      0.45
2 obj2      0.34
3 obj3      0.02
```

And now I want to add a third column. The values in the new column should contain a part of the name of the dataframe. From the datraframe-name `t.test>1sd` i want to extract `>1sd` . (In this case >1sd is a special boundary)
But I have more dataframes with different boundaries (>2sd, >3sd,...)
So I need a solution that separates `t.test` and `>1sd`

Here is my desired output:

```
> `t.test>1sd`
# A tibble: 3 x 2
object p.value    boundary
<chr>    <dbl>      <chr> 
1 obj1      0.45    >1sd
2 obj2      0.34    >1sd
3 obj3      0.02    >1sd
```

Is there a solution in the stringr-package?
Can someone help me?

Comment: Check out `?substr`

Comment: `str_extract('t.test>1sd', '\\>[0123456789]{1}sd')`

Comment: This is a very peculiar problem statement. The name of your `data.frame`/`tibble` is very awkward, and suggests to me that this is some form of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'd suggest taking a step back and revising the data generation process rather than implementing post-hoc fixes that might not generalise well and are potentially prone to introducing more inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion by LAP `str_extract('t.test>1sd', '\\>[:digit:]{1}sd')` should do the trick.